# How to write an elastic search count api in spring boot..?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Steps to write elastic search count api using spring boot.?

- how to use countRequest to get count of documents...??
- need code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Using new Java API Client:

```
var countRequestResponse = client.count(CountRequest.of(c -> c.index("idx_name")));
System.out.println(countRequestResponse.count());
```

Using Java High Client Library

```
var countRequest = new CountRequest();
countRequest.indices("idx_name");
var response = getClient().count(countRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
System.out.println(response.getCount());
```

Comment: Which version of client is stable with spring boot 2.7.2 and java 11..?
Also, Please share the class name.
I need to get count for multiple indices.

Comment: You can read more informations about version [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/_getting_started.html). Exists the property indices which you can set multiples indices.

Comment: Getting below error 
 
ElasticsearchException    [Invalid or missing build flavor [oss]]    tat org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2701)\r\n\tat org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171)\r\n\tat org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.

I am using elastic search server :- 7.6.1

Spring boot version :- 2.7.2

java version :- 11

Comment: what is version ES and java client?

Comment: My ES server version is 7.6.1  

and I want to use with spring boot 2.7.2 

java version 11 

and 

              <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
  </dependency>

es client version is showing as 7.14